# Error while loading model with RL4J

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dl4j

I'm using RL4J (the Reinforcement Learning framework integrated in DeepLearning4J) for making a car complete the lap in a track for a videogame.

I save the the model after the training with this code:

```
QLearningDiscreteConv<ScreenFrameState> dql = new QLearningDiscreteConv(mdp, RACING_NET_CONFIG, RACING_HP, RACING_QL, manager);
dql.train();
dql.getNeuralNet().save(model);
```

After the model is saved, I'd like to see how it behaves, and so I load it to play it:

```
DQN load = DQN.load(model);
QLearningDiscreteConv<ScreenFrameState> dql = new QLearningDiscreteConv(mdp, load, RACING_HP, RACING_QL, manager);
dql.getPolicy().play(mdp);
```

but it fails while loading with this error:

```
org.deeplearning4j.exception.DL4JInvalidInputException: Cannot do forward pass in Convolution layer (layer name = layer0, layer index = 0): input array depth does not match CNN layer configuration (data input depth = 109, [minibatch,inputDepth,height,width]=[1, 109, 150, 3]; expected input depth = 10) (layer name: layer0, layer index: 0)
   at org.deeplearning4j.nn.layers.convolution.ConvolutionLayer.preOutput(ConvolutionLayer.java:294)
   at org.deeplearning4j.nn.layers.convolution.ConvolutionLayer.preOutput(ConvolutionLayer.java:248)
   at org.deeplearning4j.nn.layers.convolution.ConvolutionLayer.activate(ConvolutionLayer.java:392)
   at org.deeplearning4j.nn.layers.AbstractLayer.activate(AbstractLayer.java:309)
   at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.activationFromPrevLayer(MultiLayerNetwork.java:789)
   at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.feedForwardToLayer(MultiLayerNetwork.java:929)
   at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.feedForward(MultiLayerNetwork.java:870)
   at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.feedForward(MultiLayerNetwork.java:861)
   at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.silentOutput(MultiLayerNetwork.java:1906)
   at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.output(MultiLayerNetwork.java:1898)
   at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.output(MultiLayerNetwork.java:1871)
   at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.output(MultiLayerNetwork.java:1952)
   at org.deeplearning4j.rl4j.network.dqn.DQN.output(DQN.java:49)
   at org.deeplearning4j.rl4j.policy.DQNPolicy.nextAction(DQNPolicy.java:32)
   at org.deeplearning4j.rl4j.policy.DQNPolicy.nextAction(DQNPolicy.java:18)
   at org.deeplearning4j.rl4j.policy.Policy.play(Policy.java:72)
   at org.deeplearning4j.rl4j.policy.Policy.play(Policy.java:27)
   at me.andreaiacono.racinglearning.rl.QLearning.race(QLearning.java:81)
   at me.andreaiacono.racinglearning.core.player.QLearningPlayer.race(QLearningPlayer.java:19)
   at me.andreaiacono.racinglearning.gui.GameWorker.doInBackground(GameWorker.java:56)
   at me.andreaiacono.racinglearning.gui.GameWorker.doInBackground(GameWorker.java:11)
   at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The input is correct: my screen is 150 * 109 pixel with 3 color channels; why does it expect a size of 10 when loading? What am I missing?

Thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

> (data input depth = 109, [minibatch,inputDepth,height,width]=[1, 109, 150, 3]; expected input depth = 10)

That looks like you set `inputDepth` to `109`, whereas it should be set to `3` (number of channels). I'm not familiar with `dl4j` personally, so not sure why it would say "expected input depth = 10", but I suppose you could at least try switching around the order in which you gave those arguments.

Answer (score 0):

What is the version that you use? Soetimes if you use the snapshot repository, a temporary mistake is possible, but the guys fix it really quick. So by chance you might have taken code from snapshot at this moment. Take s stable version.